# Azure - Virtual network Gateway vs VPN gateways

Tags: azure, networking

What are the differences between virtual network gateway vs VPN gateway and what determines which one to use?

The closest definition I can find is

"A VPN gateway is a specific type of virtual network gateway that is used to send encrypted traffic between an Azure virtual network and an on-premises location over the public Internet."

I'm a developer and do little bit of ops, so trying to make sense.

Comment: I find [this](https://www.techtarget.com/iotagenda/definition/gateway) post quite good. Gateways are kind of _doors_ between networks that can bring multi-protocol communication between them. VPN gateways are use case of Gateway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you found the closet definition, the VPN gateway is a **specific type** of the virtual network gateway. When you create a `virtual network gateway` resource in Azure, you can select the `VPN` or `ExpressRoute` gateway type in Azure. The VPN gateway usually means a VPN gateway type of virtual network gateway.

[image]

- [What is VPN Gateway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways)
- [ExpressRoute overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-introduction)

Answer (score 4):

Technically there are Resource Types of **Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways** and **Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways**. All ARM templates all use Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways resource type when deploying the Virtual Network Gateway - Type VPN as a standalone service. However when VPN is integrated into Virtual WAN/Hub you will see VPN Gateway (**Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways**) is used then.

| Purpose | ResourceType1 | ResourceType2 | ResourceType3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **As a VPN service outside a Virtual WAN/Hub use:** | Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways | Microsoft.Network/Connections | Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways |
| **Inside a Virtual WAN/Hub use:** | Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways | Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways/vpnConnections | Microsoft.Network/vpnSites |

Comment: but this wasn't the case when the question was asked, so its not possible that OP was asking about this. this is probably more confusing

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks alot

Comment: @4c74356b41 any people who will find this today will be more interested in the state today. And today there is `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateway`, `Microsoft.Network/vpnGateway` and `Microsoft.Network/p2sVpnGateway`. And severe problem finding which is which mainly because the configuration cannot be searched by the API resource ID.